# Printing symbol name and value in Mathematica

Tags: macros, wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to create a function `` My`Print[args__] `` that prints the names of the symbols that I pass it, along with their values. The problem is that before the symbols are passed to `` My`Print ``, they're evaluated. So `` My`Print `` never gets to see the symbol names.

One solution is to surround every argument that I pass to `` My`Print `` with `Unevaluated[]`, but this seems messy. Is there a way of defining a MACRO such that when I type `` My`Print[args__] ``, the Mathematica Kernel sees `` My`Print[Unevaluated /@ args__] ``?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) on your function, with `` SetAttribute[my`print] ``.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
Clear[my`print]
SetAttributes[my`print, HoldAll]
my`print[args__] := 
 Scan[
  Function[x, Print[Unevaluated[x], " = ", x], {HoldAll}], 
  Hold[args]
 ]
```

I used lowercase names to avoid conflicts with built-ins or functions from packages.

**EDIT:**

Just to make it explicit: I have two functions here.  One will print the value of a *single* symbol, and is implemented as a `Function` inside.  You can just use this on its own if it's sufficient.  The other is the actual `` my`print `` function.  Note that both need to have the `HoldAll` attribute.

Answer (score 10):

```
ClearAll[My`Print]
SetAttributes[My`Print, HoldAll]
My`Print[args___] := 
 Do[
   Print[
      Extract[Hold[args], i, HoldForm], "=", List[args][[i]]
   ], {i, Length[List[args]]}
 ]

ape = 20;
nut := 20 ape;
mouse = cat + nut;

My`Print[ape, nut, mouse]

(* ==>
ape=20
nut=400
mouse=400+cat
*)
```

Comment: Two notes. First one is very non-obvious - check out this code: ``i = 0;My`Print[i++]``. A generated error message is puzzling and is due to `Do` using dynamic scoping (a-la `Block`) to localize its variables (`i` here).  The executed code happens to modify `i`, which has an effect only until the next loop iteration resets `i` back - but here this matters. You can avoid this by wrapping `SetDelayed` in `Module[{i},...]` when defining the function. The second note: by wrapping `args` in `List`, you evaluate them several times, which may not be desirable if their execution trigger ...
`

Comment: ... side effects. For example, here: ``i = j = k = 0;My`Print[i++, j++, k++];{i, j, k}``, you get outputs `i++=1, j++ = 1, k++ = 3` and at the end, all of `i,j,k` are set to `4`. You can avoid this by always using `Hold[args]`.

Comment: @Leonid True, should have given it more thought.

Comment: The first one I discovered by pure chance, naming one of the variables accidentally as `i`. I did not expect this (although it is logical in retrospect), and it took me a while to understand. In any case, neither one detracts from your answer, which I upvoted. Philosophically, though, this confirms that with shorter and higher-level code we also have fewer chances for bugs.

Answer (score 9):

```
SetAttributes[MyPrint, HoldAll];
MyPrint[var_] := 
  Module[
    {varname = ToString[Hold[var]]},
    Print[StringTake[varname, {6, StringLength[varname] - 1}], 
                " = ", Evaluate[var]]
  ]
```

Comment: Didn't see Szabolcs's code before I did this. Anyway, I'll leave it up as another sample.

Comment: Apart from the `HoldAll` there is almost no overlap between Szabolcs' and your method. No need for excuses I'd say, the more varieties the better.

Answer (score 6):

Coming late to the party - one can use Listability to get a rather elegant (IMO) solution avoiding explicit loops or evaluation control constructs:

```
ClearAll[prn];
SetAttributes[prn, {HoldAll, Listable}];
prn[arg_] := Print[HoldForm[arg], " = ", arg];
prn[args___] := prn[{args}]
```

Stealing the test case from @Sjoerd,

```
In[21]:= prn[ape,nut,mouse]

During evaluation of In[21]:= ape = 20
During evaluation of In[21]:= nut = 400
During evaluation of In[21]:= mouse = 400+cat

Out[21]= {Null,Null,Null}
```

Comment: +1. Very clear! But `ToString` is not necessary - `Print[HoldForm[arg], " = ", arg]` is sufficient.

Comment: +1 very elegant, although the {Null,Null,Null} output is a small blemish

Comment: @Sjoerd Indeed, I could have suppressed the output by wrapping `prn[{args}]` in extra `(...);`, but this would look ugly :). One can call the function with a semicolon at the end, as an alternative.

Comment: I also like how you make the function valid for use with multiple arguments. It has one disadvantage though: try `prn[{ape, nut, mouse}, sheep]`. I know this is a bit farfetched, but it's not that different from passing an iterator as an argument ;-)

Comment: @Sjoerd Yes, you are right. But for me, this is more a flaw of the error-checking in my function, rather than of the core approach, since such arguments are not supposed to be passed. I could change the pattern from `args___` to `args:(Except[_List]...)`, and presumably exclude the troublesome case you mention (I did not check).

Comment: @Leonid `args:(Except[_List]...)` does not work since `Listable` attribute is applied before any of the transformation rules, try `SetAttributes[f, Listable]; f[{ape, nut, mouse}, sheep]`. It seems that for proper restriction we should remove the `Listable` attribute and implement multi-argument form in a different way: `prn[args___Symbol] := prn /@ Unevaluated[args]`.

Comment: @Alexey Yes you are right - I did not give much thought to that comment.

Comment: @Alexey In fact, while your suggested work-around  works, the reason it does is rather subtle: `Unevaluated` prevents not only the evaluation of individual elements in `args`, but also the Sequence splicing, so `Map` actually does map `prn` over the elements in the sequence, rather than be called with too many arguments and complain.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another variation of `` My`Print `` to add to the mix:

```
ClearAll[My`Print]
SetAttributes[My`Print, HoldAll]
My`Print[expr_] := Print[HoldForm[expr], " = ", expr]
My`Print[exprs___] := Scan[My`Print, Hold[exprs]]
```

... and another...

```
ClearAll[My`Print]
SetAttributes[My`Print, HoldAll]
My`Print[args___] :=
  Replace[
    Unevaluated @ CompoundExpression @ args
  , a_ :> Print[HoldForm[a], " = ", a]
  , {1}
  ]
```

Either way, the use is the same:

```
$x = 23;
f[x_] := 1 + x

My`Print[$x, $x + 1, f[1]]

(* prints:
   $x = 23
   $x+1 = 24
   f[1] = 2
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers consider the functions DownValues, OwnValues and UpValues:

```
In[1] := f[x_] := x^2

In[2] := f[x_, y_] := (x + y)^2

In[3] := DownValues[f]

Out[3] = {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> x^2, HoldPattern[f[x_, y_]] :> (x + y)^2}
```

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html