# How to apply HoldForm to a list of variables without the variables in the list being evaluated first?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am writing a debug function, which prints a variable name, and its value. I call this debug function with a list of variables from anywhere in the program. So the idea is for it to work like this:

```
debug[var_List] := Module[{values = ReleaseHold[var], i},

  For[i = 1, i <= Length[values], i++,
   Print[var[[i]], " = ", values[[i]]]
   ]
  ];
```

Now I use the above, like this

```
x = 3; y = 5;
debug[{HoldForm[x], HoldForm[y]}]
```

and I see in the console the following

```
 x = 3
 y = 5
```

But I have a large program and long list of variables at different places I want to debug. And I do not want to type `HoldForm` to each variable to make up the list to call the debug[] function. Much easier to `Map` it if possible. Less typing each time. But this does not work:

```
 debug[ Map[HoldForm,{x,y}]]
```

The reason is that {x,y} was evaluated before `HoldForm` got hold of it. So I end up with a list that has the values in it, like this:

```
 3 = 3
 5 = 5
```

I could not find a way to `Map` `HoldForm` without the list being evaluated.

The best I could find is this:

```
debug[HoldForm[Defer[{x, y}]]]
```

which gives the following output from the above debug[] function:

```
{x,y} = {3,5}
```

Since `Defer[{x, y}]` has length 1, and it is just one thing, I could not break it up to make a 2 column list like in the above example.

It will be better if I can get an output of the form

```
 x = 3
 y = 5
```

easier to match the variable with its value since I have many variables.

**question is: Any one knows of a programming trick to convert** `HoldForm[{x,y}]` **to** `{HoldForm[x],HoldForm[y]}`

thanks

Comment: For printing out "debug" values, see: [Printing symbol name and value in Mathematica](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7985052/211232)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `Thread`:

```
Thread[HoldForm[{x, y}]]
```

alternatively,

```
Map[HoldForm, Unevaluated[{x, y}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a longer alternative demonstrating use of Hold, found in Roman Maeder's Programming In Mathematica (3rd ed.), page 137:

```
e1 = Hold[{x, y}];
e2 = MapAt[Hold, e1, {1, 0}];
e3 = Map[HoldForm, e2, {2}];
e4 = MapAt[ReleaseHold, First[e3], {0}];
debug[e4]
```

x=3

y=5

Answer (score 1):

I did a PrintIt function using attributes that does what you want. I posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270643/884752, I repeat the code:

```
SetAttributes[System`ShowIt, HoldAll];
System`ShowIt[code__] := System`ShowIt[{code}];
System`ShowIt[code_] :=
   With[{y = code},
      Print[Defer[code = y]];
      y
   ]; 

SetAttributes[System`PrintIt, {HoldAll,Listable}];
System`PrintIt[expr__]:=System`PrintIt[{expr}];
System`PrintIt[expr_] := System`ShowIt[expr];
```